# Submit Image Form Validation

Tags: javascript, image, forms, validation

```
$('#submit-img').on('click', function() {
    $('#img').attr('src', $('#url').val());     
});

function validate() {
    if ($('#img').attr('src') === '../static/img/placeholder.png'){
        return false;
    }
}

<form method="post" action="/{{ curr_user }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate(this);" >
    <div class="imagey">
        <img id="img" src="../static/img/placeholder.png" onerror="this.src = '../static/img/placeholder.png'" alt="image" />
    </div>
    <span class="input-url">
         <input type="text" name = "url" id="url" placeholder="http://" maxlength="320"/>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" id="submit-img" name="op" value="Submit" class="form-submit"/>
</form>
```

This validation code does not work for me. Any guesses why?

Also, if replace the if statement in the validate function with just `alert($('#img').attr('src'))`

The alert says `Undefined`

Answer (score 0):

There's mulitple errors in your code.

First of all this creates an endless loops of 404s in the browser

```
<img id="img" src="../static/img/placeholder.png" onerror="this.src = '../static/img/placeholder.png'" alt="image" />
```

Second, it should be $('.submit-img'), not $('#submit-img'), since you've set the class attribute, not the id attribute.

Thirdly, you need to wrap jQuery code into $(document).ready(function() { ... });

After fixing that, the code works for me [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKYdP/)

[Edit:]
Ok, probably this is what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#url').on('keyup', function() {
        $('#img').attr('src', $('#url').val());
    });
});
```

When the users enters a URL, the image is shown.

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GKYdP/1/)

Comment: But submit-img is an id #confused

Comment: Fixed my code to imagey as the class - just to make it a little more clear rather than two submit-img 's

Comment: Why would you click the image though - instead you wouldn't you click the submit button?

Comment: Ah I see. Ok I appended the correct code for that. Assuming that's what you wanted to achieve: Display the image once the users enters the url.

Comment: Hmm didn't think of doing it that way - what about 'blur' instead of 'keyup' so the screen flashes less for the user?

Comment: Also how would you fix the endless 404 loop - should I just take out the onerror? Good help, so far, here, have a choco chip cookie.

Comment: THank you so much! The code works! Only one thing - what about that 404 loop - I checked my logs and didn't find it?